# Absolute continuity and FTC

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me to understand better the FTC with the Lebesgue integral:
from  my point of view, if $F$ is absolutely continuous and $F$ is mapping set $E$ onto the set $D$, then 
$m(D) = \int_E F'$.

At least, that how it works for the Riemann integral, is not it? My prof says he is not sure that it is true. But I just feel it has to be like that. Please, tell me if I am correct.
Thank you very much.
Marina

Comment: Look at Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 8.26(d).  Specialized to one dimension, it requires for your formula to be correct that $F$ be differentiable (as does your use of $F'$), that it be 1-1, and that its inverse be continuous.  Maybe these hypotheses can be weakened for one dimension.

Comment: start with, what is $E$?

Comment: I am sorry, do you mean 3rd or 4th edition of Rudin: I have the 3rd, and it has only 16 problems in chapter 8.

Comment: E is a measurable set.

Comment: I have the second edition, I'm afraid, and I was referring to section 8.26 in the body of the text, not to a problem.  By the way, Amazon thinks the third edition is the latest.  Chapter 7 in the third edition is chapter 8 in the second.

Comment: You need to assume $F'\ge 0$ or replace it with the absolute value. After that, it is just the same as change of variables. If $F$ is not monotone you might need more assumptions. I can't remember it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP says, the idea can arise from considerations of the Riemann integral.  For example the following two statements
could be handled by any calculus student (after explaining what the "measure" $m$ of an interval is).

> 1. If $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable and monotonic and $I=(c,d)$ then $$ m(F[I])= |F(d)-F(c)| = \int_c^d
>      |F'(x)|\,dx = \int_I |F'(x)|\,dx.$$
> 2. If $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable and not necessarily monotonic and $I=(c,d)$ then $$ m(F[I]) \leq  \int_c^d
>      |F'(x)|\,dx = \int_I |F'(x)|\,dx.$$

A simple example shows that, without monotonicity, the identity can fail and reduces to an inequality.  Consider $F(x)=x^2 $ and $I=(-1,1)$.  Then
$$ 1 =  m(F[I]) < \int_{-1}^{1}|F'(x)|\,dx= 2.$$

So the question is what are the more advanced analogues of this for students of analysis.

From Saks, *Theory of the Integral*, p. 227 we get:

> 3. If $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is   differentiable at each point of a measurable set $E$ then $F[E]$ is also a measurable set and  $$
>      m(F[E]) \leq  \int_E |F'(x)|\,dx.$$

There are no assumptions on $F$ other than it does have a finite derivative at each point of the set $E$. (Saks remarks that you can replace $F'$ by any finite Dini derivative, but the proof is harder.)  If you do assume that $F$ is absolutely continuous then you would know that $F$ is derivable almost everywhere in any measurable set $E$.  But such functions map sets of measure zero to sets of measure zero so you would have the same statement (without having to assume differentiability at *each* point).

As others have pointed out, if you want the equality instead
 $$ m(F[E]) =  \int_E |F'(x)|\,dx $$
you will need to add in more hypotheses (as we saw even for the Riemann integral).  If $F$ is monotonic and absolutely continuous this will work.